# How to use hunspell_stem(or a ordinary function) with tm_map?

Tags: r, text-mining

Recently I've been doing some text mining and the stemming processing is taking a lot of time (I'm working with portuguese language).

I found the `hunspell` package, that provides spell checking, corrections and stemming.

Also, a friend developed another stemming function that I've been studying (RSLP: Removedor de Sufixos da Língua Portuguesa).

But both were made to work on a char vector, and I need to make them work with the `tm_map` function that read a corpus.

I know that to make them work, I need to split the documents on the corpus into single words, but I don't know how.

Comment: Hi, I can't test because I am using an old verion of `tm` (upgrading would break my code). Basically, you wan't to use your own custom function within `tm_map`. For that you need to encapsulate it within `content_transformer`. Cf for instance https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/66739_c4422a1761bd4ee0b0bb8821d7780e12.html and `tm_transformer`help. Now your function should be something like `mytxtfoo <-content_transformer(function(txt){paste(mystemfunction(strsplit(txt, " ")[[1]]))})`

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks for your answer, it seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Now I just need some time to fully understand the RSLP function that I'm working with to try your suggestion.